# How do I create a list of 1's in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to create a list of 1's in KDB.

I've tried:

```
{1} each (til 500)
```

which worked, but is ugly. Is there a more elegant way? (I tried `'` as well, but this didn't work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'take' (`#`) operator for this.

```
q)500#1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1..
```